# Error: Please add a @NgModule annotation Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-cli, ionic4

I'm getting the below error. any help your be appreciated!.

**ERROR: Unexpected value 'Ng2DropdownModule in C:/Users/userName/../node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/src/modules/ng2-dropdown.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'TagInputModule in C:/Users/userName/../node_modules/ngx-chips/ngx-chips.d.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

This is my **`app.module.ts`**

```
import { JwPaginationModule } from 'jw-angular-pagination';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { TemplateCategoryConfigComponent } from './template-manager/template-category-config/template-category-config.component';

declare var require: any;

@NgModule({
   entryComponents: [
       components...
   ],
   declarations: [
       components...
   ],
   imports: [
       IonicModule,
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule,
       TagInputModule,
       JwPaginationModule
   ],
   exports: [
       components...

   ],
   providers: [
       { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpService, multi: true },
           /* File, */ Camera, WidgetService, DataPushService
   ]
})
export class AppModule {

   constructor(private library: FaIconLibrary) {
       this.library.addIconPacks(fas, far);
   }

   static forRoot(options?: EnvironmentOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
       return ({
           ngModule: IdcWidgetModule,
           providers: [
               EnvironmentService,
               {
                   provide: FOR_ROOT_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
                   useValue: options
               },
               {
                   provide: LAZY_MAPS_API_CONFIG,
                   useValue: { apiKey: options.googleMapAPIKey }
               },
           ]
       });
   }

}
```

This is **`my package.json`**

```
  "name": "app-lib",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.12",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.5.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.5.3",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.3.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^17.1.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "tslib": "^1.14.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.12",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.901.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.64",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.1.5",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with this issue for more then 2 days. So, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the problem appeared after upgrading angular version to 9+. try also updating `ngx-chips`. it should help

Comment: and by the way. message at nx-chips npm page stating "This repository is currently unmaintained. Please fork or use Angular Material's chips module, it got better." recommends you to use Angular Material chips, instead of this one